# Protagonist saves the world by killing monsters by transforming into different mecha using disks

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for an old anime which I watched when I was young, during the 90s. As far as I can remember:

- The earth is flat in the story
- The storyline is about this protagonist trying to save the world by killing monsters by transforming into different mecha?
- The protagonist transform by inserting a disk (?) into a device on his hand
- At the end of the first arc, the world isn't restored, and the protagonist had to return all the disks he collected to their original place
- Each time a disk is returned, one of the bad dudes will turn back to normal
- To make things clearer, it is the protagonist himself transforming

Comment: Are you sure they are "disks"? Are they cards? Could it be "Digimon"?

Comment: I'm thinking of medabot, possible?

Comment: Are you sure this is an anime? Because I can somehow remember a sentai series with your description.

Comment: http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Secret_Disks This is presumably what you are talking about @xjshiya

Comment: [Is this](http://www.tanadelletigri.info/images/MazingaZImages/mega/35.jpg) the hovercraft you're talking about?

Comment: I remembered three types of monsters and two of them died and the third bad ass monster took their spurts (cards) to become more powerful. Relate?

Comment: @Moke: That sounds like Shinzo, I also thought about it, but I'm not sure it's it.

Answer (score 4):

A few potential options, some of these are a shot in the dark hoping some of your information is mixed up:

- *Monster Rancher* - Monsters were born from disks and used to battle other monsters. Not a mecha anime and came out in 1999. Protagonist doesn't transform *most* of the time.
- *Saint Seiya* - Has transforming protagonists that look mecha-like. I don't recall any disks though, it came out in the late 80s.
- *Escaflowne* - Came out in the 90s, mecha like.

It could also be some flavor of *Digimon*, *Gundam*, etc.

Very few Mecha anime that weren't *Gundam* or *Macross* came out in the 90s that I'm aware of; but [here is a list](http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?q=&type=0&score=0&status=0&tag=mecha&p=0&r=0&sm=0&sd=0&sy=1985&em=0&ed=0&ey=2000&c%5b%5d=a&c%5b%5d=b&c%5b%5d=c&gx=0).

Answer (score 0):

i think that you are looking for [Gulliver Boy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulliver_Boy):

[image: Gulliver Boy]

It matches your specifications.